# Constructing payload in AngularJs POST calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

In my application, I need to make `POST` requests with this information:

```
          "data": [
            {
              "type": "Search",
              "thing": "{"Table":"Movie","Field":"Title","Type":"String","Value": "INPUT VALUE GOES HERE"}"
            },
            {
              "type": "Search",
              "thing": "{"Table":"Movie","Field":"Director","Type":"String","Value": "INPUT VALUE GOES HERE"}"
            },
            {
              "type": "Search",
              "thing": "{"Table":"Movie","Field":"Year","Type":"String","Value": "INPUT VALUE GOES HERE"}"
            }
          ]
```

I have directives that are simply input elements that will get the data to be placed in the "INPUT VALUE GOES HERE" spots.

My question is, can I pre-pend all of this information into the `ng-model` of my directives so that when I submit my `POST` request, I can do something like this:

```
function submitRequest(input){    
   var dataToSend = [ input.movieTitle, input.movieDirector, input.movieYear];            
   return $http({
       method: 'POST',
       data: dataToSend    
      }) 
   }
```

The input is a `$scope` variable that holds the form data collected by all three different directives

I am just unsure how to go about building long query strings like these.

Comment: Based on the OP and the comments on the answer below, I think additional code would be helpful in arriving at a clear solution.  Consider supplying the directives you are using.  Maybe set up a plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing what rkho suggested and did this:

```
var query = {
  requestId: "xxxx",
  method: "search",
  include: "title, director, year"
}
function submitRequest(data) {
  query.data = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var queryData = {
      data: {
        table: data[i].table || "default",
        field: data[i].field || "default",
        type: data[i].type || "default",
        value: data[i].value
      }
    }
    queryData["data"] = angular.toJson(queryData["data"]);
    query.data.push(queryData);
  }
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'URL GOES HERE',
    data: query
  })
}
```

This way, it's a little more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can set dataToSend to be that data array and just have the values be the appropriate input values. See the code below:

```
function submitRequest(input){
   var dataToSend = [
      {
        "type": "Search",
        "thing": "{"Table":"Movie","Field":"Title","Type":"String","Value": input.movieTitle}"
      },
      {
        "type": "Search",
        "thing": "{"Table":"Movie","Field":"Director","Type":"String","Value": input.movieDirector}"
      },
      {
        "type": "Search",
        "thing": "{"Table":"Movie","Field":"Year","Type":"String","Value": input.movieYear}"
      }
    ];
   return $http({
       method: 'POST',
       data: dataToSend
      })
   }
```

Comment: I am aware of this, but I have a drop down list of options that the user can select and search by.  For example, there may be a "ratings" option where the user can enter how many stars its rated on average.  In my dataToSend, I'll have to then add another object that includes the information of the search.

Ultimately, the search will be dynamic, it will not always be these three search criteria.

Comment: Have you considered using an Angular factory for this?

Comment: Yep, this call is inside of a factory.  I'm unsure how to build the dataToSend array dynamically depending on which search criteria the user chooses.  Depending on what the user selects from the drop down, the Table, Field, Type, and value will be different.  So I was wondering if I can have these fields filled out within the directive itself so that when ng-model is used, it already has everything filled out and I can just toss it all into an array.